# How is a Usenet group different from a normal group for ex - a Google Group?

Tags: usenet, google-groups

I've read about it [here](http://groups.google.co.in/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46854) but I do not understand.

**What is the difference - UseNet group vs Normal group?**

Comment: Usenet (not UseNet) groups _are_ normal groups, for many people :)

Comment: @grawity For small values of "normal."  :)

Comment: [is OP implying google groups are 'normal'?](http://www.facepalm.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google groups are hosted by Google themselves. Usenet groups on the other hand are hosted by a multitude of news servers. They can be accessed using the [NNTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) protocol. Usually, your service provider also hosts a mirror of some newsgroups. But independent news servers exist also.

In that sense, Usenet is decentralised, wheras google groups is centralised.

<strike>It may also be the case that groups created directly on google groups are not synchronised with the other NNTP servers out there (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).</strike> *I stand corrected.*

Comment: You're wrong.  Posts made to Google groups on Usenet groups propagate only too well to other Usenet servers.

Comment: Usenet groups on the other hand are hosted by a multitude of news servers.

I dont get it. I have not heard of anything like this before. How does this work - hosting on many different servers? What is the problem with hosting on once server??

Comment: @eSKey To understand, think of email.  What a mess if there were only one email server.  Usenet has a long history, it started before the web, in 1980.  Things were different back then. So I tied an onion to my belt, which was the style at the time. Now, to take the ferry cost a nickel, and in those days, nickels had pictures of bumblebees on them. ‘Give me five bees for a quarter,’ you’d say. Now where were we?

Comment: its eSKay!!

"Newsgroups are technically distinct from, but functionally similar to, discussion forums on the World Wide Web." - from Wikipedia.

  Now I am even more confused. How can a Newsgroup work without WWW??

Comment: @eSKay: the WWW and Usenet are totally different things. The former is what you browse with a web browser using the HTTP protocol. The latter you browse with a newsreader using the NNTP protocol. Usenet also existed long before the world wide web.

Comment: okay i get it. i assumed WWW=internet

Answer (score 4):

Once upon a time, there was service called [Deja News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_News) that used to archive all content of Usenet newsgroups. Deja News was eventually purchased by Google and became Google groups.

Comment: so, whats the difference?

Comment: It's not a difference, Google Groups is just a way of accessing the Usenet archives.

Comment: okay, i understand. one of the ways to access UseNet groups is through Google Groups.  But where are these groups created? I mean like Google Groups are created on the website http://groups.google.com , likewise where are the UseNEt groups created??

Comment: "How can I create a Usenet Newsgroup" would be an excellent question.  I think I'll ask it.

Answer (score 3):

[Usenet](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/Usenet.html) is a set of distributed discussion groups started in 1980 and available through a variety of methods and servers.

Google Groups is a web based service, provided by the company Google, which includes the Usenet groups as well as groups created for its own service.